# Как записать в файл номера строк перед текстом?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

Не знаю, возможно ли вообще такое проделать, но думаю, что возможно.

Например, у меня имеется файл file.txt, который содержит 5 строк:

```
В этом файле имеется только 5
строк, которые должны стать пронумерованными
после применения к файлу определенной команды. 
Как это сделать, я не представляю.
Если это возможно, то подскажите как
```

Как получить файл следующего формата:

```
1: В этом файле имеется только 5
2: строк, которые должны стать пронумерованными
3: после применения к файлу определенной команды. 
4: Как это сделать, я не представляю.
5: Если это возможно, то подскажите как
```

Это не д/з. Просто я не знаю как такое сделать, и возможно ли.

Comment: 2) Да, такое возможно. 1) а) построчно читать файл в цикле б) инкриментировать переменную целочисленного типа в) записывать строку обратно но уже с добавленным значением переменной из п.б.

Comment: всё, спасибо. тогда ответ не надо. сам разберусь.

Comment: Я вам код и не собирался писать, я не знаю Bash скриптов, просто знаю что в нем есть всё что нужно для реализации вашей задачи, и в гугле найти инструкцию - дело пары минут. `алгоритм - в первом комментарии, операторы - в гугле.`

Comment: `$ less -N файл`, `$ cat -n файл`, `$ vim -c 'set nu' файл`, и т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Например утилита grep, обычно используемая для поиска, умеет нумеровать найденные строки. Причем, по счастливому совпадению после номера строки она ставит двоеточие. И конечно ей можно сказать что бы она искала любую строку. Итого:

```
grep -n "" file.txt
```

Answer (score 12):

можно добавить нумерацию при просмотре файла. например:

```
$ less -N файл
$ vim -c 'set nu' файл
```

а можно пронумеровать поток строк:

```
$ nl файл
$ cat -n файл
```

и даже указать специфический формат.

например, выравнивание по левому краю, разделитель двоеточие с последующим пробелом, ширина поля с номером — 1 (это как бы задание условного минимума — номера, состоящие из более чем одной цифры, не будут обрезаться по ширине):

```
$ nl -n ln -s ': ' -w 1 файл
```

и, при необходимости, сохранить поток в *другой* файл (при наличии опции `-w` со значением `1` опция `-n`, отвечающая за выравнивание номера, теряет смысл):

```
$ nl -s ': ' -w 1 файл > другой.файл
```

Answer (score 6):

Просто добавте номера строк c двоеточием в начало каждой строки:

```
$ vim -esc'%s/^/\=printf("%d: ", line("."))/|x' file.txt
```

Используемые опции:
в *Ex* режиме (`-е - Ex mode`) выполнить безшумно (`-s - silent (batch) mode`)
команду (`-c <command>`).

Преимущество: нет необходимости в промежуточном сохранении в файл с другим именем.
Недостаток: по производительности уступает другим решениям, например с `nl`, и поэтому не рекомендуется для массовой обработки большого числа файлов.

Comment: Спасибо, именно это было необходимо!

Comment: Очень сложный подход.

Comment: @0andriy да нет, наоборот, не очень-то и сложный, учитывая то, что мистер @0xdb пояснил что делает ``-esc``.

Comment: Посмотрите ответ @Mike (это, например, мне первое, что пришло в голову) или Баракина. А вот вызывать утилиты, а по сути интерпретатор, и потом писать программу -- это двойной overkill! Однозначно минус.

Answer (score 4):

Вариант на `gawk`:

```
gawk -i inplace '{printf "%s: %s\n", NR, $0}' file.txt
```

Можно и просто `awk`, но если он не `GNU awk` то он на месте (`-i inplace`) не сможет, придется в другой файл результат сохранять. Например так:

```
awk '{printf "%s: %s\n", NR, $0}' file.txt > file1.txt
```